# Calculating percentage of overlap between 2 features from 2 different layers using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have two layers. Layer 1 has features that are property/parcels with area in acres. Layer 2 has features that are wetlands/bodies of water with area in acres. I want to calculate parcels that have for example 0% wetlands, 10% wetlands, 20% wetlands, 30% wetlands etc. to 100% wetlands.

How can I do this on ArcGIS Desktop?

Ideally, I want to find parcels/properties that have a limited number or a limited percentage of wetland coverage.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Tabulate Intersection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/tabulate-intersection.htm) tool:

> **Summary**
>
> Computes the intersection between two feature classes and cross-tabulates the area, length, or count of the intersecting features.
>
> **Illustration**
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have step by step instructions for how to use this tool?

Comment: The help for the tool is quite comprehensive.