# Calculating wetland coverage/overlay over parcels of land?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, overlay, calculate-values

I have two layers. Layer 1 has features that are property/parcels with area in acres. Layer 2 has features that are wetlands/bodies of water with area in acres.

I want to calculate the percentage of wetland coverage on each individual property/parcel.

How can I do this on ArcGIS Desktop?

Ideally, I want to find parcels/properties that have a limited number or a limited percentage of wetland coverage.

These are the shapefiles that I have (see attached image):

1. Carson Parcels (Yellow)
2. Wetlands (Blue)

People have recommended that I use the Tabulate Intersection tool. I have attempted this but have not been successful.

I am new to ArcGIS.

[image]

Comment: clip might be better for polygon data - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm then calculate the area after.

Comment: Two options: 1) clip the polygons and then calculate the area. 2) spatial join the parcels and the wetland, and then sum up all the areas

Comment: Use the tabulate intersection tool like I answered in your [duplicate question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/302844/2856)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

1. Clip wetland layer to parcel boundary
2. Use spatial join to join parcel layer to clipped wetland layer
3. Dissolve joined layer by parcel id
4. On dissolved layer open table, add numberic field, and field calculate acres
5. Finally, join dissolved layer by parcel id to original parcel layer.

This should provide you a summarized acre value for each parcel (accounting for if a parcel has one-to-many wetlands intersecting)

Comment: Thanks. Does this work for doing multiple parcels at a time or do you mean just for one parcel at a time?

Comment: Multiple, on the entire layer